# Get Android device IPv4 address while connect through Ethernet cable

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android application that will run on Android TV Box, my device can connect to network through `Wifi` or `Ethernet` cable. I need to get device `IPv4` address, now I'm able to get the address when device is connected through `Wifi` but failed to get the address when it is connected through `Ethernet` cable.

My minimum SDK version is 24, and currently as I control the devices which my application will run, my target Android versions are 7.1 and 8.0.

I use below code to get device `IPv4` address when it is connected to `Wifi`, but I cannot find a similar code for `Ethernet` cable

```java
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
int ipInt = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
String ip = InetAddress.getByAddress(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(ipInt).array()).getHostAddress();
```

I need a way to detect if my device is connected through `Wifi` or `Ethernet` and get `IPv4` properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static String getIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Edit :**
 Add Internet permission in manifest for this to work :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This should help in all cases.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is working fine. There is only 1 minor thing missing, you need to add `INTERNET` permission in `manifest` file or an exception will be thrown. Please update your answer with this minor information so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: @Ebraheem I'm glad it helped!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try something as shown below.

Check if device is connected to Wi-Fi or not. If yes, the one that you've done works perfectly fine but if not, try the **else** part from the code below.

**Step - 1:**

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Step - 2:**

```java
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
String ip = null;

if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
    int ipInt = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    ip = InetAddress.getByAddress(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(ipInt).array()).getHostAddress();
}
else{
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    ip = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    Log.i(TAG, "***** IP="+ ip);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
    }
}

return ip;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I try your solution but there is an error `error: cannot find symbol method formatIpAddress(int)`, It seems that `formatIpAddress` function has been removed.

Comment: When device is connected through `Ethernet` cable it give me something like `IPv6` address but it is not matched with the one I see from device status. Anyway thank you for your help.